# UTF-8 string as key in dictionary causes KeyError

Tags: python, dictionary, unicode, utf-8, python-unicode

I have a dictionary with unicode strings as keys. When I try to access the value I get key error, even though the printout of the key in dictionary and my key are equal:

```
>>> test = "Byggår"
>>> key = raw_dict.keys()[7]
>>> print(test)
Byggår
>>> print(key)
Byggår
>>> test
'Bygg\xc3\xa5r'
>>> key
u'Bygg\xe5r'
>>> raw_dict[test]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd_exec.py", line 3, in Exec
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'Bygg\xc3\xa5r'
```

It seems as they are encoded differently, somehow. From experimenting it seems as the key in the dictionary is encoded as octal bytes (?) http://www.ltg.ed.ac.uk/~richard/utf-8.cgi?input=xc3+xa5&mode=obytes, whilst the key I try to access the value with is encoded as hex(?) http://www.ltg.ed.ac.uk/~richard/utf-8.cgi?input=xe5&mode=hex .

The keys in dictionary are fetched from a web source, so I guess something gets messed up on the way.

Comment: You're using Python 2, right?

Comment: @zmbq: Yes, sorry. Should have said that.

Comment: Octal? Where did that come from? Oh wait, your reference site is misleading (by omission). `0xE5` is the code for a-ring *in Windows Latin1 encoding* (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc195054.aspx).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `test` is a string while `key` is a *unicode string*. See the `u` in-front of it?

You should either use Python 3, where all strings are unicode strings, or make sure to convert test to unicode before looking for it in the dictionary.

Comment: Aaargh thanks, of course that's the problem. Feel kind of silly now. I previously had other network related encoding problems so I just focused in on the wrong thing and completely overlooked that. Python 3 is not supported on my platform unfortunately… Thanks again!

Comment: Non-Unicode strings are a female dog. You have to keep worrying about encoding and decoding all the time.